# How to generate same metrics as Yolo from detectron2?

Tags: computer-vision, detectron, yolov8

Currently, by default detectron2 gives the following output
[image]

whereas I want to generate the F1 curve, precision-recall, precision-confidence curve, and confusion matrix among other metrics. Can anyone help me with this or point me in the right direction? Yolo gives these by default so want to get same metrics from detectron as well.

Comment: Interested as well!